# UI ButtonCallBack and resume Button not working?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to have a window pop up when players reach a score. That part works but when I click on one of the buttons that are called `Resume()` and `Accept()` nothing happens. Is there a reason why when pressing these there is no exit?

```c#
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FloatieConfirmScreen : MonoBehaviour {

    public static bool GameIsPaused = false;
    public ChangeFloatie activeFloatie;
    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
    public Button button1;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Start () {

        //pauseMenuUI.SetActive (true);
        //Time.timeScale = 0f;
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive (false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        //Register Button Events
        button1.onClick.AddListener (() => buttonCallBack (button1));
    }

    public void buttonCallBack(Button buttonPressed)
    {
        if (buttonPressed == button1) {
            Accept ();
        }
    }

    public void Accept()
    {
        activeFloatie.GetComponent<ChangeFloatie> ().enabled = !activeFloatie.enabled;
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm not familiar with Unity3D but `activeFloatie.GetComponent<ChangeFloatie> ().enabled = !activeFloatie.enabled;` looks like strange logic to me. Is it not possible to just `activeFloatie.GetComponent<ChangeFloatie> ().enabled = false;`?

Comment: Well as toggle it might be okey but another point: `activeFloatie` already **is** the `ChangeFloatie` component. So the `GetComponent<ChangeFloatie>()` to me seems completely redundant. Anyway it doesn't solve the problem here ;) I recommend you to add `Debug.Log("");`s to your code and watch the console if your methods are called at all or just use Breakpoints